# Rails: Making this query database-agnostic...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-agnostic

I have these two lines in my model, written for PostgreSQL:

```
named_scope :by_month, lambda { |month| { :conditions => ["EXTRACT(MONTH FROM recorded_on) = ?", month] }}
named_scope :by_year, lambda { |year| { :conditions => ["EXTRACT(YEAR FROM recorded_on) = ?", year] }}
```

I'm running PostgreSQL in production, but I'm developing with SQLite3.  How can I write those lines in a way that is database-agnostic?

Btw, "recorded_on" is formed from the following:

```
Model.recorded_on = Time.parse("Fri, 01 May 2009 08:42:23 -0400")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, found out there's a better way (thanks to [this article](http://morecode.wordpress.com/2007/01/14/querying-for-a-date-range-ruby-on-rails/)):

Basically do nothing in the model!

```
date = Date.new(year, month, 1)
Model.find(:all, :conditions => { :recorded_on => date..date.end_of_month })
```

Answer (score 0):

BETWEEN should be pretty universal: how about something like this:

```
  named_scope :by_month, lambda { |month| 
    d1 = Date.new(2009, month, 1)
    d2 = d1.end_of_month
    { :conditions => ['recorded_on between ? and ?', d1, d2]}
  }

  named_scope :by_year, lambda { |year| 
    d1 = Date.new(year, 1, 1)
    d2 = d1.end_of_year
    { :conditions => ['recorded_on between ? and ?', d1, d2]}
  }
```

If you have times, you'd need to get a little smarter with the hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: Tried this in script/console and I get this error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column "report_run_date" does not exist

??

Comment: Whoops - left my own column name in the code from testing. Fixed. It worked beautifully on *my* table though... ;-)