# ActiveRecord aggregate function: is there a database-agnostic 'EXTRACT(WEEK from date)'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, date, aggregate-functions, database-agnostic

i have a method that works just fine (with rails 3 and PostgreSQL) ; i just wonder if it's possible to make it database-agnostic :

```
FarmGatePrice.average :price, :group => 'EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date)'
```

As i understand it, methods to extract a week ISO number from a date are always database-specific.

I could use something like a virtual attribute :week as seen [here](http://ariejan.net/2007/01/12/rails-group-results-by-week-using-group_by/), but it seems the :group options only accepts raw SQL. I've also seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893617/rails-making-this-query-database-agnostic) but it doesn't fit my needs.
Another way would be to use a database view, or even to add a :week column filled by a callback method - but i'd prefer not to mess with my schema.

So, any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope - if you need to do a group by week, you're better off saving it directly in the database as an extra column set via a `before_save` callback.

As you say, extracting a week from a date is non-trivial, and so it's best to let Rails handle this rather than your database. This will improve performance too.

**Update:**

Example callback:

```
def Thing

  before_save :set week

  private
     def set_week
        self.week = self.date.cweek
     end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, but i don't get it when you say it would improve performance. Aren't stored procedures supposed to be better ? 
...and it does not answer the "how" part of the question.

Comment: I doubt that stored procedures would ever be as fast as an index on a simple integer column. Besides, stored procedures mean putting your business logic into your database - which isn't the Rails way (do some Googling to read the arguments around this). Have updated the answer with an example callback.