# time zone and group by

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

application.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'Athens'
```

entries_controller

```
from = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day-5.day
to = Time.zone.now.end_of_day

@entries = Entry.where(:published_at => from..to).group("date(published_at)").select("date(published_at) as date, count(*) as entries_count")
```

It doesn't return correct entries_count because of time zone. Anyone knows how to deal group with time zone ? Any help is appreciated.

I found something in [here](http://blog.craz8.com/articles/2009/05/10/rails-time-zones-and-custom-database-queries) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue with group and dates : [ActiveRecord aggregate function: is there a database-agnostic 'EXTRACT(WEEK from date)'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537351/activerecord-aggregate-function-is-there-a-database-agnostic-extractweek-from)

are you storing published_at in different time zones ? in this case, i would recommend to use a callback or to override the setter so that all the dates are stored in a single time zone, or in GMT time. Oh, and select() may mess with the internal logic of where() and group() because it excludes published_at from the actual SQL query.